# Kafka - ERROR Stopping after connector error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of groups must be positive

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Working on setting up Kafka running from our RDS Postgres 9.6 to Redhift.  Using the guidelines at https://blog.insightdatascience.com/from-postgresql-to-redshift-with-kafka-connect-111c44954a6a and we have the all of the infrastructure set up, and am working on fully setting up Confluent.  I'm getting the error of ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of groups must be positive. when trying to set stuff up.  Here's my config file:

```
name=source-postgres
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=16

connection.url= ((correct url and information here))
mode=timestamp+incrementing
timestamp.column.name=updated_at
incrementing.column.name=id
topic.prefix=postgres_
```

Full error:

> /usr/local/confluent$ /usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-standalone
>   /usr/local/confluent/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties
>   /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-postgres.properties
>   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka-connect-hdfs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] [2018-01-29 16:49:49,820] INFO
>   StandaloneConfig values:
>           access.control.allow.methods =
>           access.control.allow.origin =
>           bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
>           internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>           internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>           key.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
>           offset.flush.interval.ms = 60000
>           offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
>           offset.storage.file.filename = /tmp/connect.offsets
>           rest.advertised.host.name = null
>           rest.advertised.port = null
>           rest.host.name = null
>           rest.port = 8083
>           task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
>           value.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter 
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneConfig:180)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:49,942] INFO Logging initialized @549ms
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:186) [2018-01-29 16:49:50,301] INFO Kafka
>   Connect starting (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:52)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:50,302] INFO Herder starting
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:70)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:50,302] INFO Worker starting
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:113) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:50,302] INFO Starting FileOffsetBackingStore with file
>   /tmp/connect.offsets
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:60)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:50,304] INFO Worker started
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:118) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:50,305] INFO Herder started
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:72)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:50,305] INFO Starting REST server
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:98) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:50,434] INFO jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:327) Jan 29, 2018 4:49:51 PM
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors WARNING: The following
>   warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   listConnectors in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource
>   contains empty path annotation. WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   createConnector in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource
>   contains empty path annotation. WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   listConnectorPlugins in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource
>   contains empty path annotation. WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   serverInfo in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains
>   empty path annotation. [2018-01-29 16:49:51,385] INFO Started
>   o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5aabbb29{/,null,AVAILABLE}
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:744) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:51,409] INFO Started
>   ServerConnector@54dab9ac{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083}
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:266) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:51,409] INFO Started @2019ms
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:379) [2018-01-29 16:49:51,410] INFO
>   REST server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8083/, advertising URL
>   http://127.0.0.1:8083/
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:150) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:51,410] INFO Kafka Connect started
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:58) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:51,412] INFO ConnectorConfig values:
>           connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
>           key.converter = null
>           name = source-postgres
>           tasks.max = 16
>           value.converter = null  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig:180) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:51,413] INFO Creating connector source-postgres of type
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:159) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:51,416] INFO Instantiated connector source-postgres with version
>   3.1.2 of type class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:162) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:51,419] INFO JdbcSourceConnectorConfig values:
>           batch.max.rows = 100
>           connection.url =
>           incrementing.column.name = id
>           mode = timestamp+incrementing
>           poll.interval.ms = 5000
>           query =
>           schema.pattern = null
>           table.blacklist = []
>           table.poll.interval.ms = 60000
>           table.types = [TABLE]
>           table.whitelist = []
>           timestamp.column.name = updated_at
>           timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 0
>           topic.prefix = postgres_
>           validate.non.null = true  (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig:180)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:52,129] INFO Finished creating connector
>   source-postgres (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:173)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:52,130] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:
>           connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
>           key.converter = null
>           name = source-postgres
>           tasks.max = 16
>           value.converter = null  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig:180)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:52,209] ERROR Stopping after connector error
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:102)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of groups must be positive.
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectorUtils.groupPartitions(ConnectorUtils.java:45)
>           at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector.taskConfigs(JdbcSourceConnector.java:123)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.connectorTaskConfigs(Worker.java:193)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.recomputeTaskConfigs(StandaloneHerder.java:251)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.updateConnectorTasks(StandaloneHerder.java:281)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:163)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:96)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:52,210] INFO Kafka Connect stopping
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:68) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,210] INFO Stopping REST server
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:154) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,213] INFO Stopped
>   ServerConnector@54dab9ac{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083}
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:306) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,218] INFO Stopped
>   o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5aabbb29{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:865) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,224] INFO REST server stopped
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:165) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,224] INFO Herder stopping
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:76)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:52,224] INFO Stopping connector source-postgres
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:218) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,225] INFO Stopping table monitoring thread
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector:137) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,225] INFO Stopped connector source-postgres
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:229) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,225] INFO Worker stopping
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:122) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:52,225] INFO Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:68)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:52,225] INFO Worker stopped
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:142) [2018-01-29
>   16:49:57,334] INFO Reflections took 6952 ms to scan 263 urls,
>   producing 12036 keys and 80097 values 
>   (org.reflections.Reflections:229) [2018-01-29 16:49:57,346] INFO
>   Herder stopped
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:86)
>   [2018-01-29 16:49:57,346] INFO Kafka Connect stopped
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:73)

We were using DMS between our RDS Postgres (9.6) to Redshift.  It has been failing, and simply miserable, as well as almost at this point almost unweidly expensive, so we are moving into this as a possible solution. I am kind of at a wall here, and would really like to get some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a very similar issue to this, and what I found is that if the connector doesn't have configuration to tell it what to pull, it will simply error. Trying adding the following to your connector configuration:

table.whitelist=

Then specifying a list of tables to grab.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with a [JDBC Source Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html) job. The issue was that the `table.whitelist` setting was case sensitive, even though the underlying DB wasn't (RDBMS was MS Sql Server).

So my table was `tableName`, and I had `"table.whitelist": "tablename",`. This failed, and I got the above error. Changing it to `"table.whitelist": "tableName",` fixed the error.

This despite the fact that `SELECT * FROM tablename` and `SELECT * FROM tableName` both work in MS Sql Manager.